# separate events in same column to multiple columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

My current pandas dataframe includes weather data, but has an events column with multiple events I want to separate out into their own columns and make a binary classifier.
[picture of example data here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aEa2Y.png)

Comment: please format your code appropriately. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question should be specific and your relevant code should be [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pandas.get_dummies` will do the required trick. It will convert categorical variable into dummy/indicator variables. For reference [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html#pandas.get_dummies)

```
df1 = pd.get_dummies(df.Events)
df
    rain, thunderstorm  snow
0                    1     0
1                    0     1

df = df[['humidity','temp']].join(df1)
df
    humidity    temp    rain, thunderstorm  snow
0         40      45                     1     0
1         35      30                     0     1
```

Comment: @ACIE Please upvote if it helped you. You are Welcome!

Comment: I tried! Because I am new it would not count it. I will come back and do it once my rep improves. It says it was recorded but not publicly shown